# Display a INWARD & OUTWARD of Stock Quantity of Inventory in MySQL Query By Selected Date and Warehouse

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

Need a help in the query to get a desired output. Here is my Table Structure:

1. **Product**

   Here `qty` is a Stock

   | id | product_name | qty |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | Test | 5 |
2. **Purchase**

   From purchase table, we have to select a date and warehouse by ID

   | id | warehouse id | date |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | 04-03-2022 |
3. **Purchase Item**

   Inward Stock should be shown from this table

   | id | product_id | qty | purchase_id |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
4. **Order**

   From Order table, we have to select a date and warehouse by ID
   **Here detail is a warehouse ID**

   | id | detail | date |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | 04-03-2022 |
5. **Order Item**

   Outward Stock should be shown from this table.

   | id | product_id | qty | order_id |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 |

**Desired Output Should be like this:**

Where `P` means Purchase & `O` means Order

| Product name | Inward | outward | closing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test(P) | 5 |  | 5 |
| Test(O) |  | 2 | 3 |
| Test1(P) | 2 |  | 2 |
| Test1(O) |  | 1 | 1 |

**QUERIES to Generate a respective tables:**

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0990b2abee5756a18a34d5e8e96780c2)*

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
;


CREATE TABLE `purchase` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;

CREATE TABLE `purchase_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rate` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;

CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;

CREATE TABLE `order_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rate` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `product_name`, `qty`, `price`) 
VALUES
(1,  'TEST', 1, '50'),
(2, 'TEST 2', 0, '50'),
(3, 'TEST 3', 0, '50'),
(4,  'TEST 4', 0, '50')
;

INSERT INTO `purchase` (`id`, `warehouse_id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2022-03-02');

INSERT INTO `purchase_item` (`id`, `product_id`, `purchase_id`, `qty`, `rate`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2', '50');


INSERT INTO `order` (`id`, `warehouse_id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2022-03-02');

INSERT INTO `order_item` (`id`, `product_id`, `order_id`, `qty`, `rate`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2', '50');
```

Comment: It'd be much easier and quicker to help if you post the information as text - not images. Please take the time to post CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to generate the tables and populate the tables with a few sample rows.

Comment: @SOS Updated my question information as text.

Comment: Thanks. So what have you tried and where are you getting stuck? Also, please try and include the [DDL + DML statements](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dcfb1298443038ddd165fc9ba27df80c) to create and populate the tables with the sample data as well (i.e. CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements) That saves someone else from having to type it all out, which takes time....time that could be better spent just answering your question  :-)

Comment: @SOS updated question with the respective tables CREATE and INSERT Statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query which returns the format you are looking for.
I've updated it to use `date` and `warehouse_id` as parameters in the `WHERE` clause.

> ```
> with stock_movements as
> (
> select 
>   'P' PA,
>   pu.warehouse_id ,
>   pu.`date` mvtdate,
>   p.id,
>   concat(p.product_name,'(P)') Pname,
>   pi.qty pqty,
>   0 as oqty,
>   sum(coalesce(pi.qty,0)) Total
> from products p
> left join purchase_item pi
> on p.id = pi.product_id
> left join purchase pu
> on pu.id = purchase_id
> group by 
>   pu.warehouse_id,
>   p.id,
>   p.product_name,
>   pu.`date`,
>   pi.qty
> union all
> select
>   'A',
>   ord.`warehouse_id`,
>   ord.`date` mvtDate,
>   p.id,
>   concat(p.product_name,'(O)'),
>   0,
>   sum(coalesce(o.qty,0)) oqty,
>   sum(coalesce(pi.qty,0))
>      -sum(coalesce(o.qty,0))
> from products p
> left join order_items o
> on p.id = o.product_id
> left join purchase_item pi
> on p.id = pi.product_id
> left join `order` ord
> on ord.id = order_id
> group by
>   ord.`warehouse_id`,  
>   ord.`date`,
>   p.id,
>   p.product_name
> order by 
>   id
> )
> select
> PA,
> warehouse_id,
> mvtdate "date",
> id "ID",
> pname "Product Name",
> sum(pqty) "Input",
> sum(oqty) "Output",
> sum(Total) "Total"
> from stock_movements
> where mvtDate = '2022-03-02'
> and warehouse_Id = '1'
> group by
> id, pname,pa,warehouse_id
> order by 
> id,pa desc;
> ```
>
> ```
> PA | warehouse_id | date       | ID | Product Name | Input | Output | Total
> :- | -----------: | :--------- | -: | :----------- | ----: | -----: | ----:
> P  |            1 | 2022-03-02 |  1 | TEST(P)      |     2 |      0 |     2
> A  |            1 | 2022-03-02 |  1 | TEST(O)      |     0 |      1 |     1
> P  |            1 | 2022-03-02 |  2 | TEST 2(P)    |     3 |      0 |     3
> A  |            1 | 2022-03-02 |  2 | TEST 2(O)    |     0 |      1 |     2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cbdceb2a7554294e0434fdcdec502dd9)*

FIRST DB FIDDLE:
*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6d7e94af44035d838b2be5bf863a476

Comment: Thanks.. Almost, it's right, But I want like to retrieve records by passing date and warehouse id on table purchase and order. @kendle

Comment: Hi... I think I got it.. Please check this fiddle and let me know Is this a correct way of doing it? @kendle
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6a6a609f3dd1c887cbc113a74b8d5fe

Comment: I thought if that but we would have to put the date and warehouse ID twice: both sides of the Union. I'm working in a solution with a CTE but have to make time for the family. :-)

Comment: Hi.. Sorry to bother you, I added a warehouse_id column, but when I added the sum for total purchase orders in Select Statement throwing group by error.

Comment: do you have a new dbfiddle link?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb9d7943a8d2aa1057fd8e3d234bf23d Using the same one by adding a new batch.

Comment: I've added the GROUP BY in the sub-query and modified in my answer.

Comment: Yes. I checked it out. Thank you very much :-) it works correctly now.

Comment: Perfect - please accept my answer.